How to replace a quoted string with a modified version of it JQuery/Javascript
I'm looking for a solution to replace all quoted strings in a phrase with the same quoted strings but in a modified version.
This is an example of what I mean:
var str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';

//Expected output: name=--"benson"--; passowrd=--"1234"--


var str = 'I "love" and I like "programming"';

//Expected output: I --"love"-- and I like --"programming"--
// and so on

Following is my approach, I'm almost there but it seems I'm missing something. I have spent quite some time on it.
var str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';

var searching = str.match(/".+?"/gi); 

var result = str.replace(/".+?"/gi, "--" + searching + "--");

$( "p" ).html(result);

// out put: name=--"benson","1234"--; password=--"benson","1234"--


I think I would split the original string by the semicolon before attempting the replacement.

@mykaf That won't work well if there are any ; characters in the quoted strings, e.g. password="12;34"

The .replace function supports a special syntax where you can tell it to use the matching part when replacing.. (but you need to use capturing groups for this)
var str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';
var result = str.replace(/(".+?")/gi, "--$1--");

$( "p" ).html(result);

In this case, we create a mathcing group for the quoted string you want, and in the replace method we specify with $1 where the matching data of that group should be inserted in the replacement.

This solution worked great. I only have a tiny issue, what if I wouldn't like to touch anything inside the HTML tags, for example. var str='<div class="something">I would like to capture "this string only"</div>';.  Like I wouldn't like to capture whatever is inside the HTML tags such as class="something".
Kind Regards

@KarueBensonKarue This might get complicated quickly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128165 for an explanation (humorous one). You might want to use some sort html parser to first extract the text, modify it, and then re-insert it in the html..

String.prototype.replace supports a function as a replacer, that runs on every match:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement


var str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';

var result = str.replace(/".+?"/gi, (match) => "--" + match + "--");

$('#out').append(result)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>




In the replacement string you can use $& to refer to the string being replaced.


var str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';
var result = str.replace(/".+?"/gi, "--$&--");

console.log(result);




You seem to want to format each "piece" (name, password) separately, so I would split the original string by the semicolon before attempting the replacement on each element and re-joining.


const str = 'name="benson"; password="1234"';

const result = [];
str.split(";").forEach(
  subst => {
    const searching = subst.match(/".+?"/gi);
    result.push(subst.replace(/".+?"/gi, "--" + searching + "--"));
  }

)


$("p").html(result.join("; "));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>



.
